# php page to list and update sqlite

Tags: php, sqlite

I have the following code to display and modify a simple sqlite table

```
<?php
$db = new SQLite3("my_sqlite.db");
$query = "SELECT rowid, * FROM students";
$result = $db->query($query);


if( isset($_POST['submit_data']) ){

    // Gets the data from post
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $query = "UPDATE students set name='$name', email='$email'";

    if( $db->exec($query) ){
        echo "Data is updated successfully.";
    }else{
        echo "Sorry, Data is not updated.";
    }
}

?>

<table border="1">
    <form action="" method="post">

        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Email</td>
        </tr>

    <?php while($row = $result->fetchArray()) {?>
        <tr>
            <td><input name="name" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['name'];?>"></td>
            <td><input name="email" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['email'];?>"></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>

    <input name="submit_data" type="submit" value="Update Data">
    </form>
</table>
```

PROBLEM: When I change some of the information and update, the whole column changes into the same change. E.g.: if I write a the name Nick, every name changes into Nick.

Comment: If you want a specific row to be updated you must add a WHERE clause to the UPDATE statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should only do updates for one record at a time so each record needs its own update button. Attached is the corresponding `rơwid` of the record. you can use:

```
<input type="hidden"  name="rowid" value="$row['rowid]">
```

You should add a `WHERE` clause to the update statement to know exactly which records should be updated.If you omit the `WHERE` clause, ALL records will be updated!

Comment: It works, but I don't know why, I can change every row but I cannot update the first.

Comment: I think you should display the update query for the first record to the screen and then check if the elements are correct as you expect.